# Snake game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, snake-game

This is my first work in JS. It works but I would like to hear criticism of this code.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); //taking canvas by id
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var pText = document.getElementById('score');

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);
document.addEventListener("keydownCreate", keyPush);

ctx.fillStyle = "DarkGreen";
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
//-----------------------------------------------------------

var step = 35;                   //cells size

var score = 0;      //really score

var maxX = canvas.width-step;    //border for creating meal
var maxY = canvas.height-step;
var min = 0;

var meal = 0;                    //flag(meal existing) ...(in future meal count)
mealx = 0;                       //meal x pos
mealy = 0;

var key = "";      //keycode

var brd = 5;      //border to make snake cells smaller than another objects
var tail = 3;      //tail size
var pos = [];       //tail position (pos[0] - head)
var px = 0, py = 0;     //new head position
var bigHead = 0;     //flag to make another head after eating 

var time = 90;      //timer delay

for(var i = 0; i < tail; i++){  //pushing start tail
 pos.push([i*step, 0]);
}


function game(){
 //clear canvas
 ctx.fillStyle = "DarkGreen";
 ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 key = "right";
 //start timer
 var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  if(key == "esc"){//exit   
   clearInterval(timerId);
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   alert("game over");
  }
  if(key == "left" || key == "up" || key == "down" || key == "right"){//newt move
   newMeal();
   changePos();
   draw();
  }
 }, time);
}
function changePos(){//changing elements position
 for(var i = 1; i < tail; i++){
  if(pos[i][0]==pos[0][0] && pos[i][1] == pos[0][1]){
   for(var j = 3; j < tail; j++){
    pos[i].pop();
   } 
   tail = 3;
   score = 0;
  }
 }
 if(pos[0][0] == mealx && pos[0][1] == mealy){//eating 
  score++;
  meal = 0;
  tail++;
  bigHead = 1;
  pos.push([0, 0]);
 }
 for(var i = tail-1; i >= 1; i--){//new tail position
  pos[i][0] = pos[i-1][0];
  pos[i][1] = pos[i-1][1];
 }
 if(px == pos[0][0] && py == pos[0][1]){//if no changes
  if(key == "left")px-=step;
  if(key == "right")px+=step;
  if(key == "up")py-=step;
  if(key == "down")py+=step;
 }

 if(px<0)px = canvas.width-step;//new head position
 if(py<0)py = canvas.height-step;
 if(px>canvas.width-step)px = 0;
 if(py>canvas.height-step)py = 0;
 pos[0][0]=px;
 pos[0][1]=py;
}
function newMeal(){
 if(meal==0){//if no meal
  mealx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX - min) + min);//new position
  mealy = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY - min) + min);
  
  while(mealx%step){//center
   mealx+=1;
  }
  while(mealy%step){
   mealy+=1;
  }
  meal = 1;//flag(there is meal)
 }
}
function draw(){//drawing canvas
 pText.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;

 ctx.fillStyle = "DarkGreen";//claer canvas
 ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

 if(meal != 0){//draw meal  
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect( mealx, mealy, step-brd, step-brd);
 }
 
 if(bigHead == 0){//drawing head
  ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
  ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0], pos[0][1], step-brd, step-brd);
  ctx.fillStyle = "DarkGreen";
  ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0]+step/7, pos[0][1]+step/7, step/1.8, step/1.8 ); 
 }else{
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0], pos[0][1], step-brd, step-brd);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0]+step/7, pos[0][1]+step/7, step/1.8, step/1.8 );
  bigHead++;
  if(bigHead == 5){
   bigHead = 0;
  }
 }

 //drawing tail
 var clrG = 255;
 var clrR = 0;
 var str = "rgb(0, ";
 for(var i = 1; i < tail; i++){
  if(clrG<=0){
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+clrR+", 0, 0)";
   clrR+=20;
  }
  else{
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, "+clrG+", 0)";
   clrG -= 20;
  }
  
  ctx.fillRect(pos[i][0], pos[i][1], step-brd, step-brd);
 } 
}
function keyPush(evt){//key codes
 if(evt.keyCode == 37){
  if(key != "right" && key != "left"){//to avoid turn around and to avoid *jumping* through cells
   key = "left";
   px-=step;//changing head position
  }  
 }
 if(evt.keyCode == 38){
  if(key != "down" && key != "up"){
   key = "up";
   py-=step;
  }
 }
 if(evt.keyCode == 39){
  if(key != "left" && key != "right"){
   key = "right";
   px+=step;
  }
 }
 if(evt.keyCode == 40){
  if(key != 'up' && key != "down"){
   key = "down";
   py+=step;
  }
 } 
 if(evt.keyCode == 27){
  key = "esc";
 }
 if(evt.keyCode == 13){
  key = "enter";
 }
}
function upButton(){
 if(key != "down" && key != "up"){
  key = "up";
  py-=step;
 }
}
function downButton(){
 if(key != 'up' && key != "down"){
  key = "down";
  py+=step;
 }
}
function leftButton(){
 if(key != "right" && key != "left"){
  key = "left";
  px-=step;
 } 
}
function rightButton(){
 if(key != "left" && key != "right"){
  key = "right";
  px+=step;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>SnakeQQ</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  input{
   margin:10px;
   width:50px;
   height:40px;
  }
  .control{
   width:100px;
   height:60px;
  }
  p{
   text-align: -webkit-center;
   font-size:40px;
   margin: 0px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="score">
  Score: 0
 </p>
 <div style="display: -webkit-inline-box">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1050" height="560" ></canvas>
  <div>
   <div style="text-align: -webkit-center">
    <input type="button" id="play" value="play" onClick="game()"/>
    <!--<input type="button" id="map" value="create map" onClick="construct()"/>-->
   </div>
   <div style="text-align: -webkit-center">
    <div>
     <input class="control" type="button" id="up" value="up" onClick="upButton()"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input class="control" type="button" id="left" value="left" onClick="leftButton()"/>
     <input class="control" type="button" id="right" value="right" onClick="rightButton()"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input class="control" type="button" id="down" value="down" onClick="downButton()"/>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: KarthikNedunchezhiyan/MultiLevel-Snake-Game you can use this link for reference, i have made snake game using js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides what [Janos wrote in his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176415/21444) already, a few thoughts from me:

#### Inconsistent use of `var`

Some variables are declared using the `var` keyword, but others aren't:

> ```
> var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
> ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
> ```

**Note:** You can use a `,` to separate multiple declarations, like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

#### Configuration

I found it a bit hard to follow, which keys were used for what action and you often re-use color values.

To improve readability of your code and to make it more DRY you can create some sort of configuration.

Another advantage is that you can change the whole appearance and control of  the game now. You can even expose this configuration to the user, making it possible to create own game settings.

### Color and control configuration

```
var theme = {
    control: {
        up: 39,
        down: 40,
        left: 37,
        right: 38        
    },

    colors = {
        canvas: {
            background: 'darkGreen',
            gameOverBackground: 'red'
        },
        meal: {
            background: 'red'
        }
    }
}
```

Simply access the values where needed:

```
ctx.fillStyle = theme.colors.meal.background;

if (key === theme.control.left) {}
```

It is clear which key or color you're referring to and there's only one place to change it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Mutually exclusive conditions

Here, the second condition will be evaluated too, even when the first one is true. To avoid that, the second `if` should be `else if`.

> ```
> if(key == "esc"){//exit           
>   // ...
> }
> if(key == "left" || key == "up" || key == "down" || key == "right"){//newt move
>   // ...
> }
> ```

The same goes for this sequence of conditionals:

> ```
> if(key == "left")px-=step;
> if(key == "right")px+=step;
> if(key == "up")py-=step;
> if(key == "down")py+=step;
> ```

And these, and so on, you get the idea:

> ```
> if(px<0)px = canvas.width-step;//new head position
> if(py<0)py = canvas.height-step;
> if(px>canvas.width-step)px = 0;
> if(py>canvas.height-step)py = 0;
> ```

#### Variable scope

This writing style of `var i` may lead to confusions in JavaScript:

> ```
> for(var i = 1; i < tail; i++){
>   // ...
> }
> ```

Because this writing style suggests that `i` will be visible only within the body of the `for` statement, when in fact it's visible in the body of the entire function.
The recommended practice is to declare variables at the top of the function.

#### Writing style

For better readability, it's generally recommended to put spaces around operators and parentheses in conditionals. For example instead of this:

> ```
> while(mealy%step){
>   mealy+=1;
> }
> ```

Write like this:

```
while (mealy % step) {
    mealy += 1;
}
```

And instead of `mealy += 1`, you can write `++mealy` or `mealy++`.
Note that the `++` prefix and postfix operators are exempt from the recommendation to put spaces around operators.

#### Use boolean values for false and true meanings

Instead of using 0 and 1 values for `meal` to indicate false and true,
it would be better to use `false` and `true`.
And then write conditions on the value of `meal` as `if (meal)` or `if (!meal)`.

#### Duplicated logic

The `if` and `else` branches execute the same non-trivial `fillRect` operations.
It would be good to extract the 4 lines called on `ctx` into a helper function that takes two style parameters:

> ```
> if(bigHead == 0){//drawing head
>   ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
>   ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0], pos[0][1], step-brd, step-brd);
>   ctx.fillStyle = "DarkGreen";
>   ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0]+step/7, pos[0][1]+step/7, step/1.8, step/1.8 );  
> }else{
>   ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
>   ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0], pos[0][1], step-brd, step-brd);
>   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
>   ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0]+step/7, pos[0][1]+step/7, step/1.8, step/1.8 );
>   // ...
> }
> ```